# During Data Migration Getting Access Violation Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

During data migration from Magento1 to Magento2, I'm getting the following issue:-

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';   END;
>   INSERT INTO m2_cl_cataloginventory_stock_item (`item_id`, `operation`)
>   V' at line 3, query was: CREATE TRIGGER
>   codisto_cataloginventory_stock_item_delete AFTER DELETE ON
>   cataloginventory_stock   _item FOR EACH ROW

Please see the screenshot for more details

[image: Data-Migration-Issue]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can anyone have its solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134166)

Comment: Does your database user have the permission to create triggers?